# Cookie handling with Scrapy during login

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, cookies, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl some data from Amazon Mechanical Turkey, where I could only view the first few pages of the result without logging in. It turned out that Amazon requires cookies to record sessions, so the simplest way that just submit a formrequest as many examples do won't work.

I've tried to pass some cookies around, though I thought scrapy will handle that automatically, but it's not working. If I do open_in_browser after submitting the form, I get the amazon page saying that I should enable cookies in order to logging.

Then I came to another post where he uses selenium to get the cookies. I've also tried it and the same occurs.

Here's what I've got right now. I've add `COOKIES_ENABLED = True` to `settings.py`

By adding COOKIES_DEBUG to settings, I think cookies are received and set by looking at the log simply with InitSpider, without selenium. But it just wont work.

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from mturk.items import MturkItem
from selenium import webdriver

class MturkSpider(Spider):
    name = "AMT"
    allowed_domains = ["mturk.com","amazon.com"]
    start_url='https://www.mturk.com/mturk/viewhits?searchWords=&selectedSearchType=hitgroups&sortType=Title%3A1&pageNumber=1&searchSpec=HITGroupSearch%23T%231%2310%23-1%23T%23%21%23%21Title%211%21%23%21'
    login_page = "https://www.mturk.com/mturk/beginsignin"
    formdata ={'create':'0','email': 'xxx@example.com', 'password': '1234'}


    def get_cookies(self):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        base_url = "https://www.mturk.com/mturk/beginsignin"
        driver.get(base_url)
        driver.find_element_by_name("email").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("xxx@example.com")
        driver.find_element_by_name("password").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("1234")
        driver.find_element_by_id("signInSubmit-input").click()
        cookies = driver.get_cookies()
        driver.close()
        return cookies

    def start_requests(self):
        self.my_cookies =  self.get_cookies()
        yield Request(self.login_page, 
            cookies = self.get_cookies(),
            callback = self.login,
        )

    def login(self, response):
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response, 
            formdata = self.formdata,
            # cookies=self.my_cookies,
            callback = self.after_login,
        )

    def after_login(self,response):
        open_in_browser(response) # where it says I need to enable cookies
        yield Request(self.start_url, 
            # cookies=self.my_cookies,
            callback = self.parse_page,
        )

    def parse_page(self, response):
        # do the parsing, where I can successfully crawl the first few pages
```

I'm fairly new to python and this society. I have to say my knowledge is quite limited in this area and I can only learn from others' work. Anybody has some suggestions to make it work?

I've found solutions with urllib2/mechanize regarding amazon login, but no solution with Request. I thought the case was similar here?

UPDATE:
I've solved it myself.
Seems no need to use selenium at all. The problem lies in that I have to specify proper headers during submission of requests.
I manually set all headers grabbed from my browser and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, but rather than manually setting the Request headers, I found that one of the header values was for the User Agent.  Setting this value in my project's setting file did the trick and I now do not have to hard-code the header values:

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0'

or whatever value for the browser you're using.

Now, the cookies are working properly for me--automatically.